# C# dataGridView SQL SELECT

Tags: c#, sql, select

Есть DataGridView, к нему подключён источник данных, делаю запрос на выборку данных из таблицы БД.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection Search_connection = new SqlConnection(".....");
        SqlCommand Search_command = new SqlCommand();
        Search_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Search_command.CommandText = "SELECT * from [dbo].[rukovod] where concat(F_R,I_R,O_R) like @str";
        Search_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", "%" + textBox4.Text + "%");
        Search_command.Connection = Search_connection;
        Search_connection.Open();
        Search_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Search_connection.Close();
        this.rukovodTableAdapter.Fill(this.stroitelnayaFirma_DBDataSet.rukovod);
    }
```

Таблица обновляется, но данные остаются те же, что и были. 
 Прогнал Query запрос в Managment Studo, там всё работает.

 Как мне сделать так, что бы в dataGridView отображался только результат запроса?

Comment: Вы открываете коннекшн выполняете запрос и тут же закрываете. А где код который считывает результат запроса в stroitelnayaFirma_DBDataSet?

Comment: тут показано как использовать SqlDataAdapter https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: На всякий случай: использовать транслитерированные имена переменных вроде `rukovod` — это довольно специфический стиль кодирования, усложняющий чтение кода. Обычно так стараются не делать. )

Answer (score 1):

как связана ваша Search_command и rukovodTableAdapter ? Вы не правильно работаете с датаадаптером.. если в нём есть SelectCommand, то устанавливайте значение параметров туда. И не делайте `ExecuteNonQuery()`, когда вам надо получить выборку из БД.

Примерно так

```
SqlConnection Search_connection = new SqlConnection(".....");
SqlCommand Search_command = new SqlCommand();
Search_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Search_command.CommandText = "SELECT * from [dbo].[rukovod] where concat(F_R,I_R,O_R) like @str";
Search_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", $"%{textBox4.Text}%");
Search_command.Connection = Search_connection;
Search_connection.Open();
this.rukovodTableAdapter.SelectCommand = Search_command;
this.stroitelnayaFirma_DBDataSet.rukovod.Clear();
this.rukovodTableAdapter.Fill(this.stroitelnayaFirma_DBDataSet.rukovod);
Search_connection.Close();
```

Comment: Ругается на `this.rukovodTableAdapter.SelectCommand = Search_command;`

Comment: 1) Ведь ругается определёнными словами? Не стесняйтесь повторять ругательства компьютера. 2) У вас изначально в DataAdapter был настроен SelectCommand? он отличается от приведённого в тексте вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что вместо варианта `this.rukovodTableAdapter.SelectCommand = Search_command;`, который был Вам предложен, лучше сделать так:

1. Добавить в `rukovodTableAdapter` средствами VisualStudio для конфигурирования адаптеров еще один `select`, для которого она автоматически сгенерит   `myFill(...)`  (название метода `myFill` или какое-то другое Вы выберете в процессе конфигурирования);
2. и после использовать для заполнения данных конструкцию 
   `this.rukovodTableAdapter.myFill(this.stroitelnayaFirma_DBDataSet.rukovod);`

Это уменьшит вероятность сделать ошибки и получить Exception - пусть за Вас трудится Microsoft

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50599/discussion-on-answer-by---c-datagridview-sql-select).